# predict the position of an image in another image

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection

If one image is a part of another image, then how to compute the accurate location in deep learning way?
Now I could compute this by extracting and matching key points using OpenCV, but I hope to solve it with neural networks.
Any ideas to design the networks and loss functions?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is a detection problem. The simplest approach to do it is to create a a network with two heads, one for classification and the other for the bounding box (regression).
you feed your network with the image and respective label, and sum the lossess and do a backward. train for some epochs and you'll get your self a detection model that you can use to detect what you need. but its just a simple approach and it can get much more complex.

You may as well skip this and use an existing detection architecture or better framework which simplifies your life much better.
For Tensorflow I belive you can use [ObjectDetctionAPI](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and for Pytorch you can use [Detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron), [Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2), [mmdetection](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection) among others.